# Solving a 3+1D Wave Equation

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, numerical-value, electromagnetics, wave-equation

I am having some problems with finding the solution to the magnetic field, B[x,y,z,t]. Is there anything I can change to my code to obtain a solution of B[x,y,z,t] with the initial conditions and boundary conditions listed below.

```
pde = D[B[x, y, z, t], {t,2}] == -Laplacian[B[x, y, z, t], {x, y, z}]
initialcondition = {B[x, y, z, 0] == E^(-x^2 - y^2 - z^2), Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1][B][x, y, z, 0] == 0};
boundaryconditions = DirichletCondition[B[x, y, z, t] == 0, True];
wavesolution = DSolve[{pde, initialcondition, boundaryconditions}, B[x, y, z, t], {x, y, z, t}]
```

Answer (score 1):

`NDSolve` can solve it, but not `DSolve`

```
pde = D[B[x, y, z, t], {t, 2}] == Laplacian[B[x, y, z, t], {x, y, z}]
initialcondition = {B[x, y, z, 0] == Exp[-x^2 - y^2 - z^2], 
  Derivative[0, 0, 0, 1][B][x, y, z, 0] == 0}
boundaryconditions = DirichletCondition[B[x, y, z, t] == 0, True]

NDSolve[{pde,initialcondition,boundaryconditions},B,
       {x,0,1},{y,0,1},{z,0,1},{t,0,1}]
```

[image]

Note change of sign on the Laplacian, since it is already in RHS.